Easy and cheap DIY way to cover pipes next to floor
I want to cover those heating pipes.

Unfortunately, broad skirting boards are expensive and unnecessary for such a small part, and besides, getting them right across the corner and under the radiator would be hard.
What would be an easy and cheap DIY way to hide those pipes? I was thinking about using expanding foam, cutting it, and then covering it with plaster to be painted over white. Would this be a good idea and something a non-professional could do alone?

Have you considered polishing them rather than hiding them?

@MichaelHall, I think I get what you mean, and they might look nice if polished, though the hole in the floor would still look ugly.

Foam is too easy to be destroyed.Use it only if want to fix it every week or so.
Make wooden frame and wooden/gypsum lining, then paint it to needed colour - You can bet that pipes broke week after any permament solution and if make something detachable then it will work till house be destroyed.

I did exactly this using very cheap melanine board. Didn't even paint it; looks ok.

If OP has cats, then covering it with some scrap nice carpet.
